# Bundle update error on macOS BigSur (Apple Silicon M1)

Tags: ruby, bundler, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I've ruby tools installed `brew install ruby-install chruby`

and ruby 2.7 which is visible when I use `chruby 2.7` command

but when I want to update packages in gem file I got such error:

```
Fetching digest-crc 0.6.4 (was 0.6.3)
Installing digest-crc 0.6.4 (was 0.6.3) with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/Users/nysander/.gem/ruby/2.7.4/gems/digest-crc-0.6.4/ext/digest
/Users/nysander/.rubies/ruby-2.7.4/bin/ruby
-I/Users/nysander/.rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems -rrubygems
/Users/nysander/.gem/ruby/2.7.4/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake
RUBYARCHDIR\=/Users/nysander/.gem/ruby/2.7.4/extensions/arm64-darwin-20/2.7.0-static/digest-crc-0.6.4
RUBYLIBDIR\=/Users/nysander/.gem/ruby/2.7.4/extensions/arm64-darwin-20/2.7.0-static/digest-crc-0.6.4
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_deprecate_constant
Referenced from:
/Users/nysander/.gem/ruby/2.7.4/gems/etc-1.2.0/lib/etc.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_deprecate_constant
Referenced from:
/Users/nysander/.gem/ruby/2.7.4/gems/etc-1.2.0/lib/etc.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace


rake failed, uncaught signal 6

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/nysander/.gem/ruby/2.7.4/gems/digest-crc-0.6.4 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/nysander/.gem/ruby/2.7.4/extensions/arm64-darwin-20/2.7.0-static/digest-crc-0.6.4/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing digest-crc (0.6.4), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install digest-crc -v '0.6.4' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  xcode-install was resolved to 2.7.0, which depends on
    fastlane was resolved to 2.174.0, which depends on
      google-cloud-storage was resolved to 1.34.1, which depends on
        digest-crc
```

how to fix this? this is the same when I try to use terminal in normal or Roseta 2 mode

I've tried installing manually  `gem install digest-crc -v '0.6.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` but this also fails.

Any help really appreciated

Comment: Checkout my article - https://medium.com/@vishalsadriya1224/how-to-install-postgresql-node-with-nvm-ruby-with-chruby-rails-in-macbook-pro-m1-chip-4612e0a50260